# Run sql script from console and not from query analyzer in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, command-line

I have written an sql script for updating a database that runs in SQL server 2005.

I want to make those changes to the production DB server but I dont want to run the query from the query analyzer. Is there a way to run the sql script from a console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx). It gets installed together with installing the Query Analyzer.

> The sqlcmd utility lets you enter
>   Transact-SQL statements, system
>   procedures, and script files at the
>   command prompt, in Query Editor in
>   SQLCMD mode, in a Windows script file
>   or in an operating system (Cmd.exe)
>   job step of a SQL Server Agent job.
>   This utility uses OLE DB to execute
>   Transact-SQL batches.

Answer (score 2):

create a batch file that points to the script or scripts that you created and run that batch file.

Here follow [this tutorial link](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/datacenter/?p=422)